# Textbox not getting focus in iPhone6 plus safari in landscape mode

Tags: iphone, focus

I have a textbox that is not getting focus when in landscape mode for iPhone 6 plus only. Its working for all other versions.
Even if its a simple html page, it doesn't work.

Code:

```
<html>
<body style="margin:0; width: 250px; height: 500px;">
    <input type="text" id="txt1" autofocus style="border: 4px solid red; width: 90%; height:50px;">
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.